# Does the Android BluetoothGattCallback need a timely return?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to figure out if the handlers in the BluetoothGattCallback one must implement are on a separate thread or if they need a timely return. In other words, am I able to do any lengthy calculations in, say, the onCharacteristicChanged() handler or should I stash the data in a queue or invoke a separate thread and immediately return? Is there the potential to lose data if I do not return from the callback quickly (say the device is streaming data)? I don't have such a device to test with to find out but it would be nice to know how the callbacks are designed so I would know how to design my handlers.

Anyone know how this works under the hood or has sufficient experience to guess how it works? Thanks!

Comment: I still have not been able to answer this question. So far it doesn't seem to be the case but none of my internal 'in the callback' handling has been too long.

Comment: Considering the BluetoothGatt interface doesn't queue outgoing requests (i.e. you have to do things serially, one at a time) it seems possible it won't queue incoming responses either.  It would be easy enough to test by putting a sleep in your characteristic changed.

Answer (score 2):

I printed `Thread.currentThread().getId()` when I called `connectGatt()` (from `onScanResult()`) and in `onCharacteristicChanged()`

These are the annotated results.

```
06-01 11:50:38.022  12205-12205/? D/MainActivity﹕ startScanning() in thread 1  // GUI thread is 1.
06-01 11:50:38.484  12205-12217/? D/MainActivity﹕ calling connectGatt in thread 371  // onScanResult() is called in a background thread.
06-01 11:50:39.877  12205-12233/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 373 // onCharacteristicChanged() is called in a background threa.
06-01 11:50:40.906  12205-12234/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 374 // Seems like there is a pool of three background threads.
06-01 11:50:41.876  12205-12217/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 371
06-01 11:50:42.904  12205-12216/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 370
06-01 11:50:43.878  12205-12233/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 373
06-01 11:50:44.903  12205-12234/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 374
06-01 11:50:45.878  12205-12217/? D/MainActivity﹕ Characteristic changed in thread 371
```

So in conclusion, it seems like `onCharacteristicChanged()` is called in one of three background threads. I tested this with both one connected device, and three. It used three threads in both cases.

So you probably don't need to be *really* quick (to avoid blocking the GUI), but you still shouldn't take ages because you might use up the thread pool.